# info: Trying to load file 'OEMFMFileList.xml' as a FM file list ... fatal error : Error: Missing package - Creating basic IoT Core Image Powershell

Tags: powershell, raspberry-pi, iot, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I am just trying to create a basic IoT core image by following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manufacturing-guide/04-createbasicimage).

But I am always getting the below errors, whenever I run `buildimage <product name> Test` after building the BSP (`Import-IoTBSP RPi2 C:\Downloads\RPi_BSP.zip` (or) `importbsp RPi2 C:\Downloads\RPi_BSP.zip`
`buildpkg RPi2`)

```
info: Trying to load file 'C:\OEEWorkspace\Build\arm\InputFMs\OEMFMFileList.xml' as a FM file list ... fatal error : Error: Missing package: C:\OEEWorkspace\Build\arm\pkgs\test.OEM.Sample.cab

info: Trying to load file 'C:\OEEWorkspace\Build\arm\InputFMs\RPi2FMFileList.xml' as a FM file list ... fatal error : Error: Missing package:
```

I also followed this [issue](https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-adk-addonkit/issues/139) in GitHub, but couldn't find the exact issue. Have you ever faced any error something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh!. It was a silly mistake. I didn't run the `New-IoTCabPackage All` (or) `buildpkg all` after building the BSP (`Import-IoTBSP RPi2 C:\Downloads\RPi_BSP.zip` (or) `importbsp RPi2 C:\Downloads\RPi_BSP.zip`
`buildpkg RPi2`). Hence the cab files were not pushed into the Build\arm\pkgs folder.

After running the `buildpkg all` I am able to see all the required cab files in the pkgs folder, thus no error. You must do the commands in the below order.

```
PS C:\OEE>importbsp RPi2 "C:\Users\SibeeshVenu\Downloads\RPi_BSP.zip"
PS C:\OEE>buildpkg all
PS C:\OEE>newproduct OEEIoTCore RPi2
PS C:\OEE>buildimage OEEIoTCore Test
```

Once that is done, you should be able to see an output as below.

[image]